# I screwed up my application to iphone device installer in xcode please help?

Tags: iphone, xcode, terminal, broken-pipe

I had a missing file error that led me to a solution telling me this line of code would be my savior

```
sudo ln -s ../../4.3\ \(8L1\)/Symbols/Developer/ Developer
```

Instead this caused me a much greater problem and now I cannot run my application on my phone at all.  Now it is giving me a broken pipe error.  Can someone explain an easy way to undo that first line?  I have tried everything I could think of - even went as far as to upgrade to lion, uninstall xcode, reinstall new xcode, I am restoring the device now in hopes it will force xcode to recreate the folders and files I somehow screwed with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting your developer directory and re-installing Xcode should surely fix any problems you created with the aforementioned line.

Make sure you reboot the device, not sure a restore will do any good.

Comment: Ok, I will try it again.  I think when I reinstalled xcode instead of removing the old one it created a developer-old folder and was then using some things from that folder to "intelligently" grab the info it needed.  I will delete it first then install it again.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Hey - thanks again - if you hadn't said deleting and reinstalling it should work I wouldn't have figured out I screwed up the uninstall the first time and I would probably be very frustrated still.